# Why do I need to declare env_file explicitely in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I extended the Wordpress image to add XDebug, PHPUnit, composer & phpcs.

My project root looks like this:

```
docker-wordpress
    Dockerfile
docker-compose.yml
.env
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - ./docker-mysql/db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     ports:
       - "3306:3306"
     env_file: .env

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: progonkpa/mywordpress
     ports:
       - "80:80"
       - "443:443"
     restart: always
     volumes:
       - ./src:/var/www/html
     env_file: .env

volumes:
    db_data:
```

This configuration works but only because I added the env_file declaration explicitely while I thought that Docker picks up the file automatically if I followed the right conventions: .env  file in root.

I actually want to remove the env_file declarations in docker-compose.yml but then I run into some issues.

MySQL container logs:

```
database is uninitialized and password option is not specified
You need to specify one of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

I seems that on first run when the containers are initialized, my variables related to mysql don't come through. The .env file holds the usual Wordpress and MySQL variables:

```
MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
MYSQL_USER=wordpress
MYSQL_PASSWORD=wordpress
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=wordpress
WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db:3306
WORDPRESS_DB_USER=wordpress
WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=wordpress
```

So why is it that my variables don't reach my container?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There are two places you can use variables here: inside the compose file itself, and inside the containers created by`docker-compose`.

The `.env` file will be used by `docker-compose` to adjust the environment of the `docker-compose` command itself. This is useful for variable inside the yaml file that need to be expanded, or variables used by compose itself. For more on the latter, see [the compose CLI variables docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/).

Defining an `env_file` inside the yaml will take environment variables from the file and inject them into the container. That makes it visible to your application, but cannot be used for variables inside your yaml that you want `docker-compose` to expand since that variable expansion happens before the `env_file` contents are parsed.

Comment: and you can use `docker compose config` that prints our resolved application config (including **environment**) to see variable expansion, Variables Interpolation, and experiment in vivo

Answer (score 5):

Docker-compose need to be defined everything explicitly, consider it as a `docker run parameter`, it only applies those configurations or parameter on each container that is defined in the docker-compose file.

So one should avoid overriding ENV if they are already declared in Dockerfile so that is the why you need to explicitly define these configurations for your self.

when we build docker we set some default configuration in the docker-image, but `docker run command` and `docker-compose` provide the functionality to override these to change that take effect when the image starts up as a container.

> A service definition contains configuration that is applied to each
>   container started for that service, much like passing command-line
>   parameters to docker container create. Likewise, network and volume
>   definitions are analogous to docker network create and docker volume
>   create.

[compose-file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)

**env_file**

Add environment variables from a file. Can be a single value or a list.

> If you have specified a Compose file with `docker-compose -f FILE`,
>   paths in `env_file` are relative to the directory that file is in.
>
> Environment variables declared in the environment section override
>   these values – this holds true even if those values are empty or
>   undefined.

```
env_file: .env
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `docker compose config` that prints our resolved application config (including `environment` section) to see variable expansion, Variables Interpolation, and to experiment in vivo.

By using that, you be able to answer by yourself what works and what not

Answer (score 0):

Security: Storing sensitive information, such as API keys or database passwords, in a separate file provides an additional layer of security. The env_file can be excluded from version control systems (like Git), preventing accidental exposure of sensitive information.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).